# norms and sparsity

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, normed-spaces

Could anyone please elaborate on why $L^2$ norm moves toward the outliers compared to $L^1$ norm. I mean, what property/quantity in the mathematical expression of the norms makes it perform such way.

One more thing is, how $L^1$ norm introduces more sparsity in the solution?

Thank you.

Praveen

Comment: Are you dealing with L^2 norm of vectors of numerical data? Something like  $\|x\|^2=x_1^2+...+x_n^2$ and for L^1 the taxi cab/Manhattan norm, am I right?

Comment: As Avitus suggested, it would help if you told us what kind of behaviour and in what context you have in mind, exactly, maybe with a simple example.

Comment: yes, I am dealing with numerical data.

Comment: The $L^2$ norm squares each component of a vector.  If a component is large, then squaring it makes it huge, which is a disaster.  The $L^2$ norm tries hard to avoid this.  If a component is small, then squaring it makes it tiny and negligible.  The $L^2$ norm doesn't mind if a vector has many small components.  On the other hand, for the $L^1$ norm it's not such a disaster if one component of a vector is large.  And having several small components isn't preferable to having a single large component.

Answer (score 3):

I think the overall context you're referring to is the problem of $L^0$ minimization, i.e. compressed sensing. So, the goal of your question is to find the relationship between the following problems:

$(P_0)\qquad \min \|x\|_0 \;s.t.\;Ax=y\\
(P_1)\qquad \min \|x\|_1 \;s.t.\;Ax=y\\
(P_2)\qquad \min \|x\|_2 \;s.t.\;Ax=y$

Since our goal is ultimately to solve $P_0$, the problem with $L^2$ minimization is as follows:

[image: Lecture notes screen shot]

As you can see, it is generally unlikely that a matrix $A$ will have a $P_2$ solution that lies on any of the axes (i.e. a sparse solution). However, because of the "diamond-shape" of the set of equal $L^1$ norm, the $L^1$ solution is more likely to be sparse

As for your second question, here's an exercise from my own coursework that might help you understand this better

> Consider $P_1$ as described above, where $x\in\mathbb R^N, A\in \mathbb R^{m\times N},y\in \mathbb R^m$, with $m\ll N.$ Then $(P_1)$ has a solution with at most $m$ non-zero entries.  Accordingly, the solutions to the $P_1$ problem promote sparsity.

Actually proving this is an interesting exercise, and I can give you a hint there if you want it. The point is, we can guarantee a relatively sparse solution under $L^1$ minimization, which we can't generally do for $L^2$ minimization.  In fact, if $A$ has the null-space property, we find that there is a unique solution like this.

---

Here's the hint that came with the problem:

> *Hint:* suppose $\overline{x}\in\mathbb R^N$ is a solution to $(P_1)$ and $\|\overline{x}\|=k$ where $m<k\leq N$.  It follows that $k$ columns of $A$ are linearly dependent.  As a result, there exists a nonzero vector $h$ in $\mathbb R^N$ such that $Ah=0$.
>
> Define $\widetilde{x}=\overline{x}+\epsilon h$ where $\epsilon\in\mathbb R$, then $A\widetilde{x}=y$, i.e., $\widetilde{x}$ is also a solution to $y=Ax$.  Since $\overline{x}$ is a solution to $(P_1)$, we have 
>   $$\|\widetilde{x}\|_1=\|\overline{x}+\epsilon h\|_1 \geq \|\overline{x}\|_1$$
>   Therefore, we can choose $\epsilon$ such that
>
> $$\|\overline{x}+\epsilon h\|_1=\|\overline{x}\|_1 \quad \text{ and } \quad \|\overline{x}+\epsilon h\|_0<\|\overline{x}\|_0$$

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. 

I see those figures everywhere when they explain the norms. Could you please explain how they represent L2 and L1 norms, respectively...!

I fear, I may not be able to solve the exercise problem. Would you please provide me the solution, if possible...!

Thanking you.

Comment: The two curves there are curves of constant norm. The circle is the curve given by $\|x\|_2=C$ for some $C\in \mathbb R^+$, and the first is the curve given by $\|x\|_1=C$. In both of these pictures, we have found the point that minimizes $\|x\|_p$ because we have found the curve $\|\vec x\|_p=C$ that is "tangent" to the line $\vec y=A \vec x$. That is, there can be no $x$ of smaller norm on that line.

Comment: I've added the hint.  Let me know if that makes sense.  The trick to actually doing the problem, if you'd still like to do it, is choosing the appropriate $\epsilon$ to complete the proof.

Comment: That first comment wasn't so clear.  The curve on the **right** (the diamond) is the curve given by $\{x:\|x\|_1=C\}$, for some constant $C$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I could figure out and qualitatively understand the concept. But, I am stuck at the last expression. How the # non zero elements could be greater in x(bar).

Comment: That's where our very particular choice of $h$ and $\epsilon$ come in handy. I will try to type my full answer neatly if/when I have the chance. In the mean time: unfortunately, the hint doesn't say it all.  It's important that we can choose a suitable $h$ that has the same support (set of non-zero components) as $\overline{x}$ (why is this necessarily possible?). We then choose the smallest epsilon so that $\widetilde x$ has at least one more zero-element than $\overline{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

The $L^2$ norm on any space focuses more on outliers because squaring a large number makes it much much larger compared to the smaller numbers than before; then these large numbers affect the average more, and taking the square root affects everything equally, so the outliers are still influential.

For instance, if you average $2$ and $100$, the second number is 50 times the first, and it pulls the average over to $51$. But $10000$ is $2500$ times bigger than $4$, so if we square them and average them, the $10000=100^2$ dominates even more, giving an average of $5002$, whose square root is 70.725, much closer to the outlier.

Comment: I got the point. But, do we take the average of numbers in calculating the norms..!? Please correct me if I am wrong.
E.g. The L1 norm of v=(1,2,3) is 6 and L2 norm is 3.742.

Comment: You're right, for the 'normal' norms you don't average. I was thinking of general $L^2$ integrals, but it didn't come out very well. The other answer is much better!

Answer (score 0):

Note: since sparsity metrics are independent of the scale (or are 0-homogeneous), it could be interesting to look at ratio of norms or pseudo-norms (ratios are scale-independent), instead of norms, which are 1-homogeneous, see at the end.

Why does $\ell_2$ move toward outliers more than  $\ell_1$? Mostly before **errors to the square** amplify the relative weight of large distances, hence toward potential outliers.

More precisely: if you have a set of numbers $x_k$, and seek a single number $\overline{x}$ as  a central tendency to represent them all, you can find it by minimizing a suitable cost function. Minimizing the $\ell_2$ (Euclidean) norm ($\sum_k (x_k-x)^2$) yields $\overline{x}$ to be the sample average. Minimizing the $\ell_1$ (Taxicab) norm ($\sum_k |x_k-x|$) yields $\overline{x}$ to be the median (when properly defined).  This concept can be extended to (polynomial) regression, the case of central tendency representing a polynomial of degree 0. Least-square minimization is most common, least-absolute deviation is thought to be more robust. The sensitivity to outliers can be related to the derivative of the cost function. With $\ell_2$, the derivative relates to the signed distance to the objective (hence it is amplified by long-distance outliers). With $\ell_1$, the derivative relates to the sign of the position with respect to the  objective (hence it does not matter whether an outlier is far or not).

A simple example is a set of samples and one outlier: $2n$ ($n>0$) times the number $a$, and an outlier $b$. The median yields $a$ (insensitive of the outlier), the mean $\frac{2na+b}{2n+1}$, which can get as high (or low) as you want with suitable $b$. Very sensitive to only one outlier. This is the simplest example for [robust statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1164/why-havent-robust-and-resistant-statistics-replaced-classical-techniques).

For far, we talked about **cost**, or "data fidelity term": a function that measures how far observed data is from a model.

Depending on the relative dimension of the data and the model, many impose further conditions, to build simpler models. One of them is sparsity, a key concept, yet complicated in practice. A signal, a model is sparse if its number of non-zero samples/coefficients/parameters of small. This amounts to the minimization of an $\ell_0$ penalty, which is intractable in general. But under some conditions, it can be equivalent to an associated $\ell_1$ penalty  (which is tractable), for which @Omnomnomnom gave a good explanation.

Let me add that claiming that $\ell_1$ yields sparser solution is still debated in a lot in applications (signal processing, statistics). Indeed, norms are $1$-homogeneous, while the parsimony index $\ell_0$ is not (it is $0$-homogeneous). So if you multiply a vector by $a>0$, its  $\ell_1$  and  $\ell_2$ norms are modified, while the vector sparsity index has not changed.

Additional discussions are in [Why L1 norm for sparse models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45643/why-l1-norm-for-sparse-models). Recently, some works have shown interest in norm ratios (such as $\ell_1/\ell_2$), that may provide interesting proxies (ie tractable) for $\ell_0$ penalties (see for instance [Euclid in a Taxicab: Sparse Blind Deconvolution with Smoothed l1/l2 Regularization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.5465), or [SPOQ ℓp-Over-ℓq Regularization for Sparse Signal Recovery applied to Mass Spectrometry](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.08496)).